# How to use JobScheduler to replace custom Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler, jobservice

I have to listen a custom broadcast receiver that has registered in a AndroidManifest.xml, but now it doesn't work in Android O. I was given an advise that use JobScheduler API to solve this problem. I have looked at many docs and blogs, they just tell me how to use JobScheduler to replace system broadcast receiver that registered in AndroidManifest.xml, such as network status change. But I can not find a way to use JobScheduler to listen a custom broadcast receiver, any one who can help me?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "custom broadcast receiver"? Do you mean a `<receiver>` for some custom broadcast action? If so, what other apps are sending that broadcast?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I mean that. And other app will send broadcast like this: `sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.tcl.mediainfo.trace"));` Also this implicit broadcast is hardly to be modified to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

`JobScheduler` does not help in this scenario.

The authors of the app that is sending the broadcast need to update their app to either:

- Send an explicit broadcast, or
- Do something else for IPC (e.g., use a bound service)

In the meantime, your only option to receive those broadcasts is to register for them using `registerReceiver()`. That only works while you have a running process, so if you are expecting to receive the broadcasts most of the time, you will need a foreground service.

Comment: My app will not always keep running for performance optimization, I just want to wake up my app when receives the broadcast. Once the app finishes the work, it will be stopped.

Comment: @coder.john: Then you need to convince the authors of the other app to change their app.

Comment: Any solutions for this case? I have the same problem and being struggling with this for 3 days. I've tried invisible Activity + context Broadcast Receivers, Service + context Broadcast Receivers and a simple JobScheduler with no luck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @CarlosJiménez: As I noted in the answer, a foreground service should work.